# Symfony2 : parameters of the controller's router

Tags: symfony, parameters, router

I wonder if there is a difference between:

- the router I can reach from  a command script, using `$this->getContainer()->get('router')` and
- the one I can reach from a controller, using `$this->get('router')`.

I have set the base url parameter "router.request_context.base_url" in `app/config/parameters.yml`

This base url appears in urls generated by the "command" router, but not in urls generated by the "controller" router.

Did I miss something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`router.request_context.base_url` is only used by the "command" router. The router used in your controllers will use the current URL as the base URL. You have a flag to set when calling the `generate()` function in order to have the absolute URL:

```
$this->get('router')->generate('myroute'),
$this->get('router')->generate('myroute', array(), true)
```

Will output:

```
/myroute
http://development.www.myapp.com/myroute
```